# Only accept 11 digits in a IntegerField (not less than 11, and not more than 11)

Tags: python, regex, django, django-models, django-validation

I have a IntegerField, where I want the input to only accept a value of 11 digits/numbers.

I have tried to make a regex validator on the field, but my problem is when I try to make a model form with the field. I only get a validation-error if the value is 10 digits or less, but if I try a value with 12 digits and upwards, I don't get any validation error.

Here is my model field:

```
number =  models.IntegerField(max_length=11, validators=[RegexValidator(r'\d{11,11}','Number must be 11 digits','Invalid number')])
```

How can I make it so I get a validation error if the value is more than 11 digits?

Comment: you want only number or char to??/

Comment: user regex provided by M42 it is perfect for you

Comment: In your edit you seem to miss the starting anchor in M42's answer, the little `^` after the first quotation mark. With your current regex, even `bladieblaanythinghere12345678901` would be accepted, as it just looks if the string contains 11 digits followed by the ending of the string. With the starting anchor `^` it would look for the beginning of the string, followed by 11 digits, followed by the ending of the string - not allowing any other characters before/after the digits-part of your regex.

Comment: @knbk: You are correct! I was missing the `^`. Now it works! I removed my edit, because it did not add anything to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about django syntax, but you have to use anchors:

```
r'^\d{11}$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `min_length` kwarg – it works exactly as you would imagine it does:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, min_length=11,
        validators=[RegexValidator(r'\d{11,11}',
            'Number must be 11 digits', 'Invalid number')])
```